# Dúvida sobre estilização de input="submit"

Tags: css

Tenho uma seguinte classe:

```
.rodape input{
blablabla
}
```

E o seguinte HTML

```
<div class="rodape">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

O que acontece, todos os inputs dentro dessa div irão receber as definições que informei no `rodape`. Perfeito, só que, eu queria estilizar o input que tem `type="submit"` também, só que de uma forma diferente dos outros.

Não quero criar uma classe só para ele, gostaria de saber se há uma forma de fazer, informando por CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar no seletor de CSS um atributo e o seu valor, assim como também, um elemento como o **input** neste caso você poderia utilizar as duas coisas, você busca um **input** no seu **.rodape** porém o mesmo deve ter o atributo `type=submit` note que apenas se o valor for **submit** que o seletor irá aplicar.

## Observação importante:

O que está na regra **.rodape input** também será aplicado à regra **input[type=submit]** porém o que estiver na regra **input[type=submit]** plevarecerá sempre, ou seja, será mais importante, e apenas ele considerado(caso haja sobrescrita), resumindo se você tiver uma borda atribuída na regra **.rodape input** e não tiver nenhuma borda na regra do  **input[type=submit]** a borda irá ser aplicada no botão, porém se houver uma outra borda na regra do **input[type=submit]** a borda que estiver nesta regra que será considerada e a outra será descartada.

## Exemplo:

```css
.rodape input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #333;
}

.rodape input[type=submit] {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: Teal;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rodape">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Podes usar `input[type="submit"]` como seletor de CSS ou então usa um `button` e podes configurar no CSS usando `button` no seletor CSS.

Comment: Hmm... voto negativo? Aceito sugestões caso algo esteja incorreto.

Answer (score 1):

Use `input[type="submit"]` assim você consegue customizar apenas ele.

Exemplo: `.rodape input[type="submit"] { color: blue; }`

Alguns exemplos [clique aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)